# Is there any way to get OnTouchListener of View?

Tags: android, view, ontouchlistener

I am looking for method such like `View.getOnTouchListener()` similar to `View.getOnFocusChangeListener()`

Is there any other way to get `OnTouchListener` of View?

What I want is to get `OnTouchListner` of One view and set same to another view

Comment: check out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595220/android-get-view-only-on-which-touch-was-released?rq=1

Comment: no, you cannot do that

Comment: Thanks Ankush for your comment What I want is to get OnTouchListner of One view and set same to another view

Comment: you have set the listener of the first view so you know what listener you have used, so whats the problem with re-using it?

Comment: I dont know which mView is ( mView.getOnTouchListener())  having touchlistner means I add all view dynamically

Comment: sorry, i have no idea what you mean

Comment: Thanks pskink for your support